Memory Leak in torch.load() with PyTorch
I've discovered a memory leak in torch.load() when loading a saved tensor. Despite explicitly deleting the loaded object and invoking garbage collection, the memory usage does not decrease as expected.
Below is a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the issue.
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
import torch
import gc

def create_and_save_image():
    image = torch.randn(30, 384, 384)
    ckpt = {"image": image}
    torch.save(ckpt, "test_image.pt")

@profile
def load_and_del():
    ckpt = torch.load("test_image.pt")
    del ckpt
    gc.collect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_and_save_image()
    load_and_del()

Steps to Reproduce:
python3 -m memory_profiler mem_leak.py
Observe the memory usage before and after loading and deleting the tensor.
Expected Behavior:
The memory usage should increase when torch.load() is called and decrease after the object is deleted and garbage collection is invoked.
Observed Behavior:
The memory usage increases when torch.load() is called, but does not decrease after deleting the object and calling gc.collect(), indicating a memory leak.
System Information:
PyTorch version: 2.3.0
Python version: 3.8.5
OS: Linux
CUDA version: 12.0
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX A6000 (48 Gb)
Additional Information:
I have used memory_profiler to profile the memory usage, and it confirms that memory is not being freed as expected. Here’s the output of the memory profiler:
memory_profiler
